# How add together all numbers from a file separated by a non digit

Tags: python

For instance, 3.145 would be the sum of 3 and 145. 21,756.54 would add three numbers: 21, 756 and 54. Assuming this file has words as well as numbers, how would I get just the numbers, and then split them at commas and periods and then add them together.

This is what i have so far

fileName = (input("Enter the name of a file to count: "))

```
infile = open(fileName,"r")
for line in infile:
    for ch in line:
        if ch >= "0":
            if ch <= "9":
                print(ch, end = "")
```

All this does is give me all the numbers in the file in one long string. I need them split at their commas and decimals and then add them together. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Just to make sure: you don't have to worry about signs?

Comment: Why do you need to treat commas and periods specially in the first place? If you split on all non-digits, you've already eliminated the commas and periods along with the spaces and letters and whatever else might be there. You _could_ of course split on all non-digit-comma-or-period, and then split on all comma-or-period, but what would that gain?

Comment: I guess they don't need to be treated specially. I'm just not sure how to split on more than one character with the str.split() function. How would I split on all non digits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use regex with a greedy `+` to pull out all the numbers:

```
import re
with open(fileName,"r") as f:
   nums = re.findall("[0-9]+", f.read())
   sum(map(int,nums))
```

Answer (score 1):

[`replace`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) all `,` with `.`, [`split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) on the `.`, [`map`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) each element to `int`, and [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) those elements:

```
>>> line = '21,756.54'
>>> sum(map(int, line.replace(',','.').split('.')))
831
```

Answer (score 1):

You are going to want to use regular expressions here. In regular expressions `\d` represents all digits. So the following would split all numbers into a list and then you can just `sum`:

```
import re
with open(fileName,"r") as f:
    list_of_numbers = re.split(r'[^\d]',f.read())
    answer = sum(map(int,list_of_numbers))
#answer is now the sum of those integers
```

the expression `[^\d]` can be explained as follows:

`[^...]` means everything **except for** the characters supplied by ..., so `[^\d]` means every non-digit character